# Problem with derivatives for spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

I got stuck with a derivative. I can't think of a solution for this, because I am taking the derivative of a function with respect to its integral. Theta and phi are generalized coordinates. I am looking to find some kinetic energy derivatives for lagrangian.

My work is as follows:
$$T = \frac{1}{2} m \ell^2[\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta\dot{\varphi}^2]$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{\varphi}} = \frac{1}{2}m\ell^2\cdot2\sin^2\theta\dot{\varphi}=ml^2\sin^2\theta\dot{\varphi}$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial \varphi} = \frac{1}{2}m\ell^2 \, \frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\left(\sin^2\theta\cdot\dot{\varphi}\right)$$

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is theta? If there is no dependence on phi, the derivative should be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Lagrangian formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), the [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) are the coordinates and their time-derivatives (i.e., the velocities). Thus, you shouldn't think of $\dot\phi$ as *depending* on $\phi$ but as a *distinct parameter* of the system. Thus, when you take the derivative in question, you would obtain
$$
\partial_\phi\left(\sin^2\theta\,\dot\phi\right)=0
$$
because there is no $\phi$-dependence in the parenthesis.

What you can make of this term being zero is that, unless there is a term in the potential energy that depends on $\phi$, the momentum in the $\phi$ direction is a [conserved quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_quantity) because you will end up with
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\phi}\right)&=\partial_\phi L=0 \\
\Rightarrow\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\phi}&=\text{const}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand, it should be zero because there is no explicit dependence on phi.

And this makes sense since the kinetic energy (and equations of motion) in this case should not depend on your choice of coordinate systems (should be independent of rotations around the z-axis).

For the same reason in Cartesian coordinates, the kinetic energy will not depend on x,y,z because it is the same m/2 v^2, here, there and on the moon.

And if all you have is this kinetic energy the equation of motion should remind you of conservation of..... (task for you)

Comment: In its current form (v5) this seems to be an answer to the question; I've removed some comments which seem to debate previous versions.